# Tracing (step-by-step) some other function call in pdb

Tags: python, pdb

I'm in the middle of tracing in PDB, at some line. I want to call other function (`foo`) to see result. I can do it by just typing `foo()`.

But I want to 'step' into `foo`. How can I do it?

(To clarify, current line does not contain `foo` calls).

Comment: you mean, while debuging current line, you call another function and do debuging there ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I want to call some other function in step-by-step mode. It's imported, but it's not called on the current line.

Comment: maybe pycharm debugger or use pdb their in that function

Answer (score 0):

You can jump in the program to the line where the desired function is called. Prepare arguments if they are omitted as a result of the jump. Enter the function with `step`. For example:

```
def foo(n=5):
    result = [n]
    result.append(2)
    return result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    k = 1
    breakpoint()
    m = 2
    f = foo(m)
    print(f)

-----------------------------

> c:\users\ф\pycharmprojects\matrix\ггг.py(11)<module>()
-> m = 2
(Pdb) j 12
> c:\users\ф\pycharmprojects\matrix\ггг.py(12)<module>()
-> f = foo(m)
(Pdb) m = 22
(Pdb) step
--Call--
> c:\users\ф\pycharmprojects\matrix\ггг.py(2)foo()
-> def foo(n=5):
(Pdb) 
> c:\users\ф\pycharmprojects\matrix\ггг.py(3)foo()
-> result = [n]
(Pdb) 
> c:\users\ф\pycharmprojects\matrix\ггг.py(4)foo()
-> result.append(2)
(Pdb) 
> c:\users\ф\pycharmprojects\matrix\ггг.py(5)foo()
-> return result
(Pdb) 
--Return--
> c:\users\ф\pycharmprojects\matrix\ггг.py(5)foo()->[22, 2]
-> return result
(Pdb) 
> c:\users\ф\pycharmprojects\matrix\ггг.py(13)<module>()
-> print(f)
(Pdb) 
[22, 2]
--Return--
> c:\users\ф\pycharmprojects\matrix\ггг.py(13)<module>()->None
-> print(f)
(Pdb) 

Process finished with exit code 0
```